# No graphics memory?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, gpu, intel-core-i3

I recently upgraded to Core i3 on H55 chipset, and using the integrated GPU on the chip.

I installed AOE III, on running, it shows me an error saying that `.. graphics memory is 0mb .. min reqd is 64mb`.

I have 2GB DDR3 memory on board.

So, the GPU must be sharing it, right? why is it showing 0mb?

Even moving a window results in lag! Please help.

Comment: Have you installed the drivers?

Comment: drivers for what exactly? I just installed Xp.

Comment: @sathya okay. i was just checking http://in.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=qWmZUAdNKeozTOXb&templete=2. There are 2 drivers for VGA and 1 for the chipset. which one will solve my problem?

Comment: I cannot access that page now, just grab the newer drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install all drivers from [ASUS's drivers page](http://in.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=qWmZUAdNKeozTOXb&templete=2).

That should fix it. Seems like you're currently on "safe" driver.